# Ruby AWS-SDK: How to list the parent checks of a health check

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ruby

I have a job that cleans out unused health checks. Some of them cant be deleted if they have a parent check resulting in the error:

`Invalid parameter : Health check SOMEHEALTHCHECKID is still referenced from parent health check(s): SOMEHEALTHCHECKID-PARENT`

How can I list the parents of a health check? I would like to be able to obtain the id of the parent check in a method that is more stable than parsing the error message string.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to collect all the health checks in route53 and parse them for any that matched the `CALCULATED` config type:

`check[:health_check_config][:type] == "CALCULATED"`

Then after getting the `Aws::Route53::Errors::InvalidInput` error during health check deletion, I would search through my parent check collection to see if any parent check included the failed check in its `child_health_checks` array:

```
parent_checks = parents.select{|parent_check| 
  parent_check[:health_check_config][:child_health_checks].include?(check[:id])
}
```

I could then delete all the matching parent checks and retry the regular deletion after.